# Plugin form block not displaying block title

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have a custom ctools plugin for D7, which displays a form inside of a block. But when I set the block's title, it doesn't display on the page with the block on it. However, if I set the block's title for the administration screen it does display there.

Here is my code:

```
function hobsons_interest_pane_custom_pane_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $contexts) {

$myform = drupal_get_form('hobsons_interest_form');

    if (!empty($contexts)) {
    $content = drupal_render($myform);
    }

    $block = new stdClass();

    //   var_dump($conf['override_title_text']); // THIS HOLDS THE PROPER TITLE


    $block->title = $conf['override_title_text']; // NO TITLE GETS RENDERED

    $block->content = $content;

  return $block;

}

/**
 * 'admin info' callback for panel pane.
 */
function hobsons_interest_pane_custom_pane_admin_info($subtype, $conf, $contexts) {
  if (!empty($conf)) {
    $block = new stdClass;
    $block->title = $conf['override_title_text']; // THIS TITLE GETS RENDERED ON THE ADMIN EDIT SCREEN
    return $block;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function hobsons_interest_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['hobsons_interest'] = array(
    'info' => t('Hobsons Interest Form'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}
```

My guess is that using drupal_get_form() is somehow to blame, but it's just a guess. Thank you!